# logoff/reboot/shut-down/quit script but how to do the logging?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script to help you to decide whether to log-off, reboot, shut-down, or just quit the script, and I've got a rudimentary form of logging for it. But it only logs the question being asked, how do I get it to log the reply as well and put a time/datestamp on when it occurred please?

```
#!/bin/bash
log="/home/$USER/logs/reboot.txt"
killbrowser="/usr/bin/killall chrome; /usr/bin/killall chromium"
exec > >(tee -a $log) 2>&1
echo
{
read -n1 -p "$(tput setaf 1)  Do you want to logoff, reboot, shutdown or just quit? [l/r/s/q] " lrsq
   case "$lrsq" in
        [Ll]* ) $killbrowser; exit && exit;;
        [Rr]* ) $killbrowser; sudo /sbin/reboot $*; echo; exit;;
        [Ss]* ) $killbrowser; sudo /sbin/shutdown $*; echo; exit;;
    [Qq]* ) echo; exit;;
    * )
esac
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution could be to add this line before the `case`:

```
echo "Answer: $lrsq" >> $log
```

Small thought: I don't believe that the kill browser part is anyhow necessary before issuing reboot or shutdown as the same will be issued by the system automatically.

To add timestamp:

```
echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S) Answer: $lrsq" >> $log
```

(use [man date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) to check format options)

Comment: Thanks, that logs the reply but doesn't timestamp it. I prefer to kill the browsers explicitly, before reboot/shutdown especially so as it also logs me out of 'fluxbox' too.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, although I did add another 'echo; ' before your timestamp line to force a new line in the log.